# Running Google App Engine test server on iPhone

Tags: macos, google-app-engine

I'm currently running Google App Engine server on my `localhost:8080`, and everything works fine. However, now I need my iPhone to be able to make requests too. I can't just access localhost on my iPhone, so I set up web sharing on my Mac, and my computer web address is `192.168.1.106/~mohabitar`. However, accessing this address from my computer or from my iPhone only lists a directory of files, it doesn't actually run my Python scripts.

How can I configure Google App Engine test server to run through my mac Web Sharing address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to supply the `--address=0.0.0.0` [command line parameter](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver#Command_Line_Arguments) when starting dev server (also for the [python version](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Command_Line_Arguments)).

Comment: Wait so do I have to put my app folder in my Sites folder in the mac? Or can I keep it where it is (desktop currently). And how would the line look to start it? `dev_appserver.py Users/mohabitar/sites/myapp`?

Comment: I dont know about OS X web sharing. You can access dev server directly after you use above parameter. Just point your iphone to http://192.168.1.106:8080 (assuming dev server runs on port 8080)

Comment: I get an `AppConfigNotFoundError`

Comment: the app folder is on my desktop. I do cd desktop/appfolder, where I have an app.yaml file and inside that an app named "myapp", so I do dev_appserver.py myapp, but I get the above error..

Comment: You are awesome my friend, everything just works now. Thanks!